# Align icon just left to the text in Button android

Tags: android, image, button, android-drawable

I have a button and I want to put an image just left of the text of the button.

```
    Button b = new Button(this);

    l.addView(b);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams pa = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -2);

    b.setLayoutParams(pa);
    b.setText("Prueba");

    Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(img, null, null, null);
```

However button width match parent and image align left of button and text is align center of button.

EDIT:

I see this

[image]

..but i want image to align just left text and not just right of the left edge of the button

I want to see like this:

http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/6534/img20130404111534.jpg

Any idea?

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: see image that i put in my question. Image is align to left of the text but not just left of the text..

Comment: Image is already at Left, but where do you want text to be?

Comment: I want to see like the last photo i put in my question (sorry, i forgot to put it before)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams pa = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

if you want to set gravity
use this

```
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams pa = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 pa.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
```

Comment: -1 is the same that LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT and -2 is the same that LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT!